# How to get value of ng-model used in radio?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How to access checked checkbox value in controller?
Here radio buttons array fill many radio buttons.

```
<label class="item item-input" ng-show="item.types !=''">
    <div ng-repeat="type in item.types" style="margin-left:5px;">
      <label class="item item-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="param.type">
        <div class="item-content">
          {{type.name}}
        </div>
        <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
</label>
```

And Controller code

```
$scope.addItem = function(params) {
    alert(params.type);
};
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: Your description is very unclear, do you want to see which radio buttons are selected? Or do you want to see the value of the selected radio button?

Comment: `addItem` should be used as a function on `ng-click="addItem(params)"`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you didn't post the rest of your controller code, I can't say for sure that this is the problem (or your only problem), but I suspect that changing `ng-model` to `type` and changing `params.type` to `$scope.type` in your `addItem` function would do the trick.  Like so:

```
<label class="item item-input" ng-show="item.types !=''">
  <div ng-repeat="type in item.types" style="margin-left:5px;">
    <label class="item item-radio">
      <input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="type">
      <div class="item-content">
        {{type.name}}
      </div>
      <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
    </label>
  </div>
</label>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.addItem = function(params) {
  alert($scope.type);
};
```